# flutter pub get failed (-10737418819) - self-signed SSL certificates blocked?

Tags: ssl, flutter, dart, ssl-certificate, dart-pub

This has been a problem for myself and my colleagues who have also tried this for quite some time (we keep revisiting the issue to try and fix) whereby the process of getting the packages for a flutter app fails. It works perfectly from my home pc but in work it does not.

Running `flutter pub get` from my cli returns `pub get failed (-10737418819)`. If I append `-v` to `flutter pub get` I get much more information which describes the HTTP get it attempts to make which is:

https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
with an accept header of 'application/vnd.pub.v2+json'

If I then use a tool such as Postman to send a Http Get with this information, it fails and reports that it could be down to:

> Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
>   Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General

So I turn this setting off and it works as expected, returning JSON data about the cupertino packages. I think the fix to my problem has something to do with SSL certificate verification but I don't know where to start. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Issue is from server side as the Website does not has SSL Certificate and you are trying to access with "https".

use the Same URL we "HTTP" it will work

Comment: No I think its do with a self signed certificate being used from my side which is not trusted by pub.dartlang

Comment: i think the issue is from server as i faced this last month